# Setting properties for Spring boot with docker compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

I have created a spring boot application that runs perfectly on my machine. I run it with Intellij. I use a application.yml file within the src/main/resources directory that contains this kind of data:

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: 'off'
  jpa:
    database: MYSQL
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: validate
        format_sql: true
        show_sql: true
```

I have quiet a few properties so this is just a small part of the properties file.

Now I want to deploy the spring boot with docker compose. I install docker and docker-compose and this is how my docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: '2'
  services:
    backend:
      image: backend:latest
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
      env_file:
        - backend.env
```

My backend.env file looks almost like the application.yml in my project however with different values like different mysql url etc

Now when I start the backend with

```
docker-compose up backend
```

I get a message that the project is still trying to connect to the database specified in the project application.yml. In short docker compose isn't overriding the properties passed on to my spring boot project.

I am wandering if my approach is the right one. What is the best practice for a Spring boot project that is deployed in docker compose? How can I deel with different environment files for each environment?

Thanks

Comment: Post the content of backend.env

Comment: Your `backend.env` should contain values like `SPRING_MAIN_BANNER=off" it shouldn't be a YAML file.

Comment: M. Deinum that did the trick. Excellent solution. Indeed the environment file must look like a properties file and not yml structure.